# create row number by group, using python datatable

Tags: python, py-datatable

If I have a python datatable like this:

```py
from datatable import f, dt
data = dt.Frame(grp=["a","a","b","b","b","b","c"], value=[2,3,1,2,5,9,2])
```

how do I create an new column that has the row number, by group?. That is, what is the equivalent of R `data.table`'s

```
data[, id:=1:.N, by=.(grp)]
```

This works, but seems completely ridiculous

```py
data['id'] = np.concatenate(
                [np.arange(x)
                    for x in data[:,dt.count(), dt.by(f.grp)]['count'].to_numpy()])
```

desired output:

```
   | grp    value     id
   | str32  int32  int64
-- + -----  -----  -----
 0 | a          2      0
 1 | a          3      1
 2 | b          1      0
 3 | b          2      1
 4 | b          5      2
 5 | b          9      3
 6 | c          2      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Datatable now has a [cumcount](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/cumcount.html) function in dev :

```py
data[:, [f.value, dt.cumcount()], 'grp']

   | grp    value     C0
   | str32  int32  int64
-- + -----  -----  -----
 0 | a          2      0
 1 | a          3      1
 2 | b          1      0
 3 | b          2      1
 4 | b          5      2
 5 | b          9      3
 6 | c          2      0
[7 rows x 3 columns]
```

**Old Answer:**

`datatable` does not have a cumulative count function, in fact there is no cumulative function for any aggregation at the moment.

One way to possibly improve the speed is to use a faster iteration of numpy, where the for loop is done within C, and with more efficiency. The code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126435/7175713) and modified for this purpose:

```py
from datatable import dt, f, by
import numpy as np

In [244]: def create_ranges(indices):
     ...:     cum_length = indices.cumsum()
     ...:     ids = np.ones(cum_length[-1], dtype=int)
     ...:     ids[0] = 0
     ...:     ids[cum_length[:-1]] = -1 * indices[:-1] + 1
     ...:     return ids.cumsum()


counts =  data[:, dt.count(), by('grp', add_columns=False)].to_numpy().ravel()
data[:, f[:].extend({"counts" : create_ranges(counts)})]

   | grp    value  counts
   | str32  int32   int64
-- + -----  -----  ------
 0 | a          2       0
 1 | a          3       1
 2 | b          1       0
 3 | b          2       1
 4 | b          5       2
 5 | b          9       3
 6 | c          2       0
[7 rows x 3 columns]
```

The create_ranges function is wonderful (the logic built on cumsum is nice) and really kicks in as the array size increases.

Of course this has its drawbacks; you are stepping out of datatable into numpy territory and then back into datatable; the other aspect is that I am banking on the fact that the groups are sorted lexically; this won't work if the data is unsorted (and has to be sorted on the grouping column).

Preliminary tests show a marked improvement in speed; again it is limited in scope and it would be much easier/better if this was baked into the datatable library.

If you are good with C++, you could consider contributing this function to the library; I and so many others would appreciate your effort.

You could have a look at pypolars and see if it helps with your use case. From the h2o benchmarks it looks like a very fast tool.

Comment: Fantastic!  Works like a charm.. True, have to do a sort prior to this, but in my instance, that was required anyway, because I need a certain order with in the groups. On my 60 million row dataset, this was reduced from ~25 seconds (with my loop above) to about 1.2 seconds.. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to convert [to_pandas](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame/to_pandas.html), [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) (on the pandas DataFrame) and use [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount):

```
import datatable as dt

data = dt.Frame(grp=["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c"], value=[2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 9, 2])

data["id"] = data.to_pandas().groupby("grp").cumcount()
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
   | grp    value     id
   | str32  int32  int64
-- + -----  -----  -----
 0 | a          2      0
 1 | a          3      1
 2 | b          1      0
 3 | b          2      1
 4 | b          5      2
 5 | b          9      3
 6 | c          2      0
[7 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: appreciate the quick response, but I was hoping for something fast.. On my ~60million row dataset, with about 3 million groups, the R approach takes about ~2.5 seconds, while both your pandas approach, and my verbose numpy concatenate arange approach takes ~30 seconds...

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using datatable and not pandas directly?

Comment: speed. I find pandas intolerably slow.