# Which is the optimal way creating a stack of arrays, when the array is not initialized?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say that I have an array `M` and I want to get rid of some blocks of rows. Indeed, I want to do something similar to what the following code implements (where `bot_indices`, `top_indices` and `M` are well defined somewhere else in the code):

```
for i_bot, i_top in zip(bot_indices, top_indices):
        M_new = np.vstack((M_new, M[i_bot:i_top]))
```

The problem is that, in the first iteration of the `for` statement, `M_new` is not defined, so I will get a `NameError`. To overcome this problem, I've thought to add a `try`/`except` statement:

```
for i_bot, i_top in zip(bot_indices, top_indices):
        try:
            M_new = np.vstack((M_new, M[i_bot:i_top]))
        except NameError:
            M_new = M[i_bot:i_top]
```

Now, the problem is that, if this block of code is embedded within a `for` or `while` statement, as `M_new` already exists the second time that the block shown is accessed, it will end up containing a concatenation of all arrays generated everytime block is accessed. In other words, I would need to "initialize" `M_new` at the end of the block shown (maybe with a `del(M_new)`?).

Which is the optimal (in terms of readability, run-time and length of code) way of tackling this problem?

Comment: Can you give some example data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The problem is that, in the first iteration of the for statement, M_new is not defined, so I will get a NameError" Maybe you can instead think of a value that you could assign for `M_new` before the loop, that makes the right thing happen the first time through the loop? Hint: if you were building an ordinary `list` by `.append`ing elements, what initial value would you use? An *empty* list (`[]`), right? So, maybe something similar exists here. Hint: what are the dimensions of `M[i_bot:i_top]`? What would the dimensions be if `i_bot == i_top`?

Comment: @Karl, modeling an array iteration on lists is not  a good idea.  list append is in-place.  Array  'append' makes a whole new array each time.

Comment: Collect the arrays in a list, and do just one `vstack` at the end.

Comment: @hpaulj True. I am trying to teach problem-solving techniques, though, not simply the appropriate in-context solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filtering `M` and appending the result to a new array, you want to do the filtering in one step:

```
filter_indices = np.array([0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 13])
M[filter_indices]
```

You can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126435/636626) to create a common range of indices from your indices, and filter `M` in one single operation:

```
import numpy as np

def create_ranges(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    l = a[:,1] - a[:,0]
    clens = l.cumsum()
    ids = np.ones(clens[-1],dtype=int)
    ids[0] = a[0,0]
    ids[clens[:-1]] = a[1:,0] - a[:-1,1]+1
    out = ids.cumsum()
    return out

M = np.random.rand(1024, 1024)
bot_indices = [10, 20, 60]
top_indices = [15, 30, 100]

limits = np.asarray([bot_indices, top_indices]).T

filter_indices = create_ranges(limits)
filter_indices
# array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, ...])
M[filter_indices]
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, @Nils (I apologize for answering so late, but this code belongs to a personal project to which I could not dedicate much time this month). So, as far as I see, the idea is to avoid using `for` instances with `arrays`, as this slows down the code. Thank you!