# 'Expanding' dataframe into matrix index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a data frame with the three columns

| colc | fpc | lpc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 | 8 |

and so on. fpc and lpc can be nan, and colc are integers. I need to turn this into the form

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 8 |

as those are the row and column index of a matrix.

I currently use the following to tranform the original dataframe.

```
def unstack_pixels(pix, fpc, lpc, colc = 'col_2'):
    
    a = pix[[colc, fpc, lpc]].dropna(how='any')

    return np.column_stack([
            np.repeat(a[colc], a[lpc] - a[fpc] + 1),
            np.concatenate([
                np.arange(start, stop + 1) for start, stop 
                    in zip(a[fpc], a[lpc])
            ])
        ])
```

However, I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it...?

Comment: It's unclear what should happen if you have NaNs, you can drop them, consider another value, etc. Please clarify

Comment: NaN should be dropped, since I cannot get a range from it.

Comment: ok then my approaches below should work and your problem could just simplify to a case in which you don't have NaNs, just doing a `df = df.dropna()` beforehand ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) and [`numpy.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) combined with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)+[`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) to generate an indexer:

```
from itertools import starmap

# if NaNs:
df = df.dropna()

out = pd.DataFrame({'a': df['colc'].repeat(df['lpc']-df['fpc']+1),
                    'b': np.r_[tuple(starmap(slice, zip(df['fpc'], df['lpc']+1)))],
                    })
```

Or with [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) and [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
n = df['lpc'].sub(df['fpc']).add(1).fillna(0)

out = pd.DataFrame({'a': df['colc'].repeat(n),
                    'b': df['fpc'].repeat(n)
                           .pipe(lambda s: s+s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()),
                    })
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  3
0  1  4
0  1  5
1  4  7
1  4  8
```

Comment: Thanks! The second method is more efficient than my existing one :) This will save me a lot of processing time!

Comment: [numpy only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126435/7175713) might also be another option

Answer (score 1):

You can use a range join to efficiently get your matches - [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) solves this. Kindly share your performance tests when you can.

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

numbers=pd.Series(range(df.fpc.min(), df.lpc.max()+1),name='b')

(df
.rename(columns={'colc':'a'})
.conditional_join(
    numbers, 
    ('fpc','b','<='),
    ('lpc','b','>='),
    df_columns='a',
    right_columns='b')
)
   a  b
0  1  3
1  1  4
2  1  5
3  4  7
4  4  8
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
df["b"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: range(
        int(x["lpc"]) if pd.isna(x["fpc"]) else int(x["fpc"]),
        int(x["fpc"]) + 1 if pd.isna(x["lpc"]) else int(x["lpc"]) + 1,
    ),
    axis=1,
)

df = df.explode("b").rename(columns={"colc": "a"})[["a", "b"]]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   a  b
0  1  3
0  1  4
0  1  5
1  4  7
1  4  8
```